# Table elements appear under the table header when scrolling

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Vue and bootstrap to create a table:

```
 <b-table 
                   striped
                   hover
                   responsive="true"
                   :no-border-collapse="true"
                   :items="items"
                   :fields="fields"
                   :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
                   primary-key="userId"
                   :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
                   :sticky-header="tableHeight"
                   sort-icon-left
          >
```

When I scroll the table, the sticky header works, but it doesn't look great because the elements from the body of the table are still visible under the header:

[sticky header issue demo](https://youtu.be/6Efd2Aod_kM)

Is there a way to preserve the stickiness but make the elements from the body of the table invisible if they are "under" the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background on your header is transparent, which is why you can see the body rows behind it.

You'll need to use CSS to make the background-color solid instead.

Comment: I noticed that the 4th parameter in my hsla wasn't "1", causing the issue: { 'background-color': `hsla(197, 65%, ${percent}%, .69)`, 'align': 'center', 'min-width': '150px' }